# What is the big o of print( list[453])? I think it would be O(1)

Tags: python, computer-science

What is the big o of print( my_list[453])? I think it would be O(1).

I think the answer would be big O(1) because its just printing that one value

Comment: This depends on what you are defining your input size to be. Would you consider `print("x")` and `print("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")` to have the same complexity?

Comment: Big O for what? Time or space? Either way, the answer depends on the actual values behind `my_list` and its 453th entry. For something like `[1, ...., 453]` you are right. For a `my_list` that isn't actually a list and has a custom  `[]` operator and/or a big entry (e.g. `2**x` or even an object with a more complicated `str` function) the complexity depends on those.

Comment: accessing the value in the list

Comment: Accessing is O(1), but your post specifically asks about printing.

Comment: its an example of a line of code that is accessing the value

Comment: As is said in my answer, the time complexity of just accessing a particular index will be O(1) i.e. constant time

Comment: Dissenting opinion: I say the question is meaningless—unanswerable. The point of big O notation is to say how the time/space/whatever _scales_ with different values of some parameter. But there is no parameter in `print(my_list[453])`. If you had asked about `print(my_list[N])`, then the answer clearly would be O(1) because, _all other things being equal,_ choosing different values for N does not change the amount of time it takes to print the item.

Comment: Also note: Some answers below say that it depends on what value is in the array slot to be printed. But that too is meaningless unless it can be tied to the parameter N. If we happen to know that each `my_list[N]` contains a string that is N characters long, then the time complexity becomes O(N), but if the contents of the array are not specified, then it's not fair to say that the answer depends on the contents.

Answer (score 2):

**Accessing a particular index in array is constant time operation.** However, time taken by print may depend on the underlying data stored in list[453]

Comment: Yes, but that does not change the big O notation.  Big O doesn't care how long the operation takes.  It says "if the list is 4 times as long or 100 times as long, how does that change the time?"  In this case, it doesn't change it at all.  So, it's `O(1)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think you misunderstood the remark about the 453th element. It is not about the 453, it is about calling the `str` function of that object. Calling `str` for a small int like  `1` has a different time complexity than calling `str` for an object like `{"this entire", "set", "is stored", "as the 453th entry", "of my_list"}`.

Comment: @Socowi -- and I think you misunderstand what I said.  The cost of the `str` is totally irrelevant to the O notation.  If the list contains complicated objects, it will take longer to render, but the time involved will not change based on the size of the list.  That's what big O denotes.

Comment: @TimRoberts Like the author of this answer, I am considering the *combined* time complexity of `print()` *and* `[]`. For that, the cost of `str` *is absolutely relevant*. For `my_list = [*range(454)]` the time complexity of `print(my_list[453])` is O(1). But for `my_list = [*range(453), [*range(x)]]` the time complexity is O(x). This is independent of the length of the list, but not constant either.

Comment: If `print(my_list[0])` always had time complexity O(1), you could solve all solvable decision problems (be they in N, NP, or even EXPTIME) in O(1): Implement them inside a custom class whose `str` function does not care about representing the object, but solves the problem (time cost does not matter) and returns either `yes` or `no`, pack your custom object inside a list, and print the list entry like OP did. -- Congratulations on your [1000000$ for proving P=NP](http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/p-vs-np-problem).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Python wiki's TimeComplexity page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list), accessing a list is indeed O(1).

`print()`ing a value may incur e.g. a complex `str()` operation on the value, so that depends, not to mention the possible complexity of the underlying I/O operation(s).